# in C++, is std::move still preferred when calling a function that takes in a const reference?

Tags: c++

Of the two versions of function calls below, is the one with std::move still preferred?

```
void myFunc(const std::string& myStr){
 //
}

std::string MyStr = "my string";

//For these 2 versions, should I still prefer std::move here to save a value copy, even when the function itself takes in a reference?
myFunc(std::move(MyStr));
myFunc(MyStr);
```

Comment: I'm missing something here. One of the big points of passing by reference is not needing to make a copy. The way I'm looking at it, if you want to avoid a copy, `move` should be irrelevant.

Comment: depends on what you want. If you want to get rid of ownership of `MyStr`'s data, then move. Else, don't.

Comment: Both calls to `myFunc` do exactly the same - create a const reference to `MyStr` - nothing else - no moving, no copies. And no change to the state of `MyStr`.

Comment: Do you really believe `myFunc(MyStr)` _does_ pass a copy by value? Or is there something inside `myFunc` you're not showing us?

Comment: In this code, there isn't (and never was) a reason to use `std::move`. The function takes its argument by reference, so there is no copy. The function takes its argument as a `const`, so it cannot modify the original argument (absent some shady practice), so it cannot move the value.

Comment: `std::move()` depsite it's name does not move anything, it just makes moving possible. But in this case that possibility is useless as it would not be used, so calling `std::move()` is redundant here. But in theory you may leave it as it shows your intention and can be used later if function overload for `myFunc()` would be added.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the function accepts by w/e way. Are you done with the object? Are you okay with losing ownership of its current contents?  Then `std::move`. If a new overload is added that can leverage the move, your code is more efficient by virtue of just recompiling. If there is never a new overload, you are not worse off than you were not moving. Consider `std::move` as an annotation on *your object*, don't go examining function signatures to see if the annotation nets a gain immediately, that may lead to premature pessimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a value by reference `std::move` doesn't make any sense, because no instantiation is happening here, and there would be no side effects (provided you don't want to alter overload function candidate)

Thus for this particular case there is no any difference and you don't need `std::move`